# What does this certain function refer to?

Tags: javascript, function

I was analyzing this piece of code (new to javascript) that is part of a simple flappy bird game but cant figure out what does this function `this.x = width` refer to. Exactly what does the `width` mean.

Some context

```js
  function Pipe() {
  this.spacing = 175;
  this.top = random(height / 6, 3 / 4 * height);
  this.bottom = height - (this.top + this.spacing);
  this.x = width;
  this.w = 80;
  this.speed = 4  ;

this.highlight = false;

  this.hits = function(bird) {
    if (bird.y < this.top || bird.y > height - this.bottom) {
      if (bird.x > this.x && bird.x < this.x + this.w) {
        this.highlight = true;
        return true;
      }
    }
    this.highlight = false;
    return false;
  }

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    if (this.highlight) {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    rect(this.x, 0, this.w, this.top);
    rect(this.x, height-this.bottom, this.w, this.bottom);
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.x -= this.speed;
  }

  this.offscreen = function() {
    if (this.x < -this.w) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this one.

Comment: The snippet is incomplete, so it's rather hard to say. If you tried to run that you'd get an error.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, `width` is referencing a variable that must have been defined outside of `Pipe()` function.  Same goes for `height`.